# IAM that created eks I wonder how can I have system:master

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I am a junior developer studying eks.

When you create eks, you can see that the IAM user used to create it is granted as system:master.

I can't find how system:master is specified

I can't see the contents of IAM in the generated aws-auth configmap of Kubernetes.

Can you find out which part to look for?

Started out of curiosity and still looking:(

please help i've been looking all day

Answer (score 2):

`I can't find how system:master is specified`

system:masters is a logical group [defined](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/registry/rbac/escalation_check.go#L38) in kubernetes source. This is not something created by EKS or yourself.

`see the contents of IAM in the generated aws-auth configmap`

kubectl get configmap aws-auth --namespace kube-system --output yaml

Try this [beginner guide](https://medium.com/the-programmer/aws-eks-fundamentals-core-components-for-absolute-beginners-part1-9b16e19cedb3).

Comment: thank you! It's been a lot of help:)